# Error in the path of an IIS server in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small web application in Asp.net.
Everything works fine on my computer. When I publish on my IIS server I get this error:
**Exception details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Generic error in GDI +.**
The error is generated by this line:

```
                bitmap.Save(cPathImage + "Immagini/tempimage.bmp");
```

cPathImage is HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");

This is the interesting part of the error stack on the IIS server:

**Sicaweb._Default.CreateImage() in D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb\Default.aspx.cs:184**

The folder D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb is the one present on my pc, it doesn't exist on the server and I don't understand where it comes from.
If I check the cPathImage variable on the server it is C:\inetpub\sica\
I don't really understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself, it was caused by Visual Studio which restores the permissions of the folders with each publication.
Thanks to those who gave -1 for no reason.